# How to fill in the gaps in the crossfilter group.all() results?

Tags: crossfilter

I have a data set defined as such:

```
var hour = data.crossfilter.dimension(function(d){ return d.date.getHours() + d.date.getMinutes() / 60; });
var hours = hour.group(Math.floor);
```

The generated result (`hours.all()`) looks like this:

```
[0, 124]
[1, 25]
[2, 5]
[3, 2]
[5, 339]
[6, 11648]
[7, 16334]
[8, 15919]
[9, 14078]
[10, 13816]
[11, 14646]
[12, 15079]
[13, 13718]
[14, 13947]
[15, 14055]
[16, 13995]
[17, 16166]
[18, 14958]
[19, 13991]
[20, 12769]
[21, 10638]
[22, 3939]
[23, 892]
```

Notice that there is a data gap between `3`, `5` (`4` is missing). How to configure crossfilter to fill in the gaps with `0` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to fill them in yourself, because I don't see how Crossfilter could group a value you don't give to it. That responsibility should fall to whatever object you're using to present the data.

Are you using d3? I think the linear scale would do that automatically. If not, it would be pretty trivial to do manually.

Comment: It wasn't straightforward at all, though I did it using vanilla JavaScript. The essentially problem comes to determining the "step size." I've tried numerous approaches, though ended up hard-coding the value depending on the `crossfilter` group settings. Keep in mind that data steps can be integers, floats or even Date value.

Comment: True, that would make things challenging.  Glad you got it figured out. Here's a formula I use to determine if a given array is continuous, though I use it to determine whether I should use `filterRange` or apply the array to the `filter` function arguments with crossfilter pull request #36.  Might help you.  (Max + step) - min === array.length * step